# Matrices: Same eigenvalues and first line

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Can we find two (different) matrices, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$
with the same

- first row (R1): $(5,3)$

  eigenvalues

Comment: What do you mean by first line? I ask specifically because your question implies the matrices are $2\times 2$, yet your 'first line' has $3$ entries.

Comment: yes! thank you! now it's correct.

Comment: Is line 1 referring to values in a row, or in a column, or something else?

Comment: I mean 'row', thank you again! (edited)

Answer (score 3):

Let $M=\pmatrix{5&3\\a&b}$. Then its characteristic polynomial is

$$p_M(\lambda)=\det\pmatrix{\lambda-5&-3\\-a&\lambda-b}=(\lambda-5)(\lambda-b)-3a=\lambda^2-(5+b)\lambda+(5b-3a)$$

Let $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ be the roots of $p_M(\lambda)$. Then

\begin{align}\tag{1}\label{eq1}\lambda_1+\lambda_2&=-(5+b)\\
\tag{2}\label{eq2}\lambda_1\cdot\lambda_2&=5b-3a\end{align}

It follows that if $A,B$ have the same eigenvalues, then equation $\eqref{eq1}$ implies that $b$ is the same for both of them. This in turn implies via $\eqref{eq2}$ that $a$ is the same for both of them. Therefore, if $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues, then $A=B$, so the answer to your question is **no**.

Comment: Very simple solution. It was easier than I thought, thank you very much!